# trapping setter exception thrown by PropertyInfo.setvalue

Tags: c#

I have a situation where placing a try-catch around SetValue on a PropertyInfo from classA does not trap an exception thrown by the setter for the classA property. How do I trap this case? Example below:

```
  public class classA
{
    private string _ID;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            if (_ID == null) _ID = value;
            else throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

    }
}

public class classB
{
    public void DoMagic()
    {
        classA MyA = new classA();

        PropertyInfo pi = GetPropertyInfoForProperty(typeof(classA), "ID");
        try
        {
            pi.SetValue(MyA, "This works fine", null);
        }
        catch { }

        ///MyA.ID = "The first time you set it everything is cool.";

        try
        {
            MyA.ID = "This throws a handled exception.";
        }
        catch { }


        try
        {
            pi.SetValue(MyA, "This Throws and Unhandled Exception", null);
        }
        catch { }

    }

    private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfoForProperty(Type type, string p)
    {
        foreach (var pi in type.GetProperties())
            if (pi.Name == p)
                return pi;
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception detail that is not getting caught? Are you seeing a message such as "Exception was thrown by the target of invocation"? By the way, I couldn't reproduce the issue in LinqPad.

Comment: Have you made sure the exception isn't thrown the by GetPropertyInfoForProperty() methods? Does it work when you use reflection to SetValue a first time?

Comment: Please show the code of function "GetPropertyInfoForProperty"

Comment: the message is InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code   {"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."}  which is the exception i intentionally throw.

Comment: I've edited the post with a runable set of example code including all functions.

Comment: not an answer but you could change your method to `return type.GetProperty(p);`

Comment: @Mario J Vargas i updated the code - it will produce the error as i described if you invoke DoMagic() in classb.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code, I think the problem is a logical error in the ID setter for the `classA` class. Currently the code is:

```
public class classA
{
    private string _ID;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            if (_ID == null) _ID = value;
            else throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

    }
}
```

The above will always throw an `InvalidOperationException` when ID receives a value other than `null`. It will always work if you set it the first time, but not subsequent times. I was going to suggest rearranging the `if` statement in your setter but then I realized that perhaps your intention was to make the `ID` property settable only once, as below, but it would throw the same exception when you attempt to set it the first time, so this won't work.

```
public class classA
{
    private string _ID;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            // This will always throw an exception
            if (_ID == null) 
            {
                // Is this what you intended? 
                // That is, throw an InvalidOperationException if a null value is supplied?
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            _ID = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Having said that, I'm still not clear with why the ID should be set only once, assuming my understanding is correct, but you can try modifying your logic so the ID is set via the constructor and making the ID setter `private`. Unfortunately, this will force you to modify the rest of the code you intended to do. Without much information, this is my best answer. Note that, by convention, I'm throwing an `ArgumentException`, but you can also throw an `ArgumentNullException`. My decision for the former is due to my use of the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method.

```
public class classA
{
    public string ID { get; private set; }

    public classA(string id)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            throw ArgumentException("id");
        }

        ID = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: The intent is to make ID settable only once - the use of a constructor for this purpose is generally what i would do, however i need to serialize/deserialize this object to XML and as such I require a default constructor. There are workarounds to aviod the throwing of the exception - but it still doesnt explain why I can not trap the exception with a try-catch around the pi.SetValue(), which is the crux of my issue. The code I posted is just an example of where this issue could arrise. I use try-catch over large portions of code to catch error conditions so I can log them. I cant do that here.